# Java 2d game tiled map clipping?

Tags: java, dictionary, 2d

Well I've created a simple tile map loading, from .txt file & then drawing.

```
25
15
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So if the current tile is 1, it will be a green block.

Now the game window looks like this (ignore yellow dots at top):

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/2dc01f6057372a6db5e5173387c60f42.png))</sub>

Okay everything is fine and great, but now can you see the red box? that's the character, and when it walks, I don't want it to go over the gates (any green block).

How can I do that?

My attempt:

```
private void makeClips() {
    int[][] tiledMap = this.map.getMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.map.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.map.getWidth(); j++) {  
            if (tiledMap[i][j] == 1) {
                clips.add(new Clip(j * 30, i * 30, 0, 0));
                System.out.println("Added clip: " + j + " " + i + " " + (j + 30) + " " + (i + 30));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should create an array of clips, so we can check if player's next walk equals to the clips coordinates, but I've had problems with setting the clip x, y like what will it's position be.

The 30 is the tile size, so each block will be 30 width 30 height sized.

And then in the walking method i've done this:

```
    for (Clip clip : clips) {
        if (myPlayer.getX() + x >= clip.getFirstX() && myPlayer.getX() + x <= clip.getSecX() 
                && myPlayer.getY() + y >= clip.getFirstY() && myPlayer.getY() + y <= clip.getSecY()) {
            System.out.println("Bad");
            return;
        }   
    }
```

But I don't know, this is 100% incorrect, mostly the coordinate calculating part.

What would you do in this case?

This is the drawing part for map:

```
private void renderMap(Graphics2D g) {
    int[][] tiledMap = this.map.getMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.map.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.map.getWidth(); j++) {
            int currentRow = tiledMap[i][j];

            if (currentRow == 1) {
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }
            if (currentRow == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            }           
            g.fillRect(0 + j * map.getTileSize(), 0 + i * map.getTileSize(),
                    map.getTileSize(), map.getTileSize());

            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            for (Clip clip : clips) {
                g.fillRect(clip.getFirstX(), clip.getFirstY(), 2, 2);

            }
        }           
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a check every time you move your player on the tile you want to move him onto.

Lets assume the player is at (0,0) on this small map.

0 0 1

0 0 0

0 0 0

We will try and move him to the right twice. The first time will work as at the position (1,0) the tile is equal to 0. The second time we try this the tile at (2,0) will return 1 and the player won't move.

```
if (tiledMap[player.getX() + 1)[player.getY()] == 1) {
//do nothing
} else {
//move player
}
```

Comment: @ljantis well my tilesize is 30 so i do player.getY() / 30 but then if its not > 0 , it won't work, only if its > 0, the clippign will work?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to do that. From what I understand of your implementation is that each coordinate is a single pixel and you are simply drawing it to make it look like its 30x30. So from the picture it will appear the player is moving 30 pixels in any direction but in your tiled map he simply moves one square e.g from tiledMap[x][y] to tileMap[x][y+1] to move him down one.

Comment: Yes but if I will use the player x without dividing by 30, i will get out of bounds.

Comment: If you give me a link to a github repo or similar I can take a longer look at your implementation.